# How to merge two sorting functions?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'm using the following class to sort the list by `type` member:

```
public class CameraSortByType : IComparer<Camera>
{
    private bool asc;

    public CameraSortByType(bool a)
    {
        this.asc = a;
    }

    public int Compare(Camera x, Camera y)
    {
        if (x.type > y.type)
            return asc? -1 : 1;
        if (x.type < y.type)
            return asc? 1 : -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm also sorting the same list by `name`:

```
myList.Sort((s1, s2) => s2.name.CompareTo(s1.name));
```

How can I incorporate sorting by name into sorting class by type? So when I sort by type it also sorts by name?

Update: Linq version

```
var primarySortResult = primarySort ? CameraStorage.CameraList.OrderBy(x => x.type) : CameraStorage.CameraList.OrderByDescending(x => x.type);
var secondarySortResult = secondarySort ? primarySortResult.ThenBy(x => x.name) : primarySortResult.ThenByDescending(x => x.name);
CameraStorage.CameraList = secondarySortResult.ToList();
```

Comment: well, if it can be inside my `CameraSortByType` then it's fine.

Comment: Nope, I asked about option `list.OrderBy(x => x.type).ThenBy(x => x.name)`

Comment: It looks nicer, but hardly I can touch the outer sorting routines.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Could you make your comment as an answer? Maybe I could go that way. For now I've tried that but it won't sort the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LINQ is an option you can use following operators to create ordered sequence:

- [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) - sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order
- [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx) - sorts in descending order
- [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) - performs subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in ascending order
- [ThenByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534736.aspx)- subsequent descending ordering

Sample:

```
var orderedList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.type)
                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.name)
                        .ToList();
```

If you need to order based on some conditions:

```
var result = ascendingByType ? myList.OrderBy(x => x.type) :
                               myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.type);

if (orderByNameRequired)
{
    result = ascendingByName ? result.ThenBy(x => x.name) :
                               result.ThenByDescending(x => x.name);
}

orderedList = result.ToList();
```

Consider also using [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

---

Also here is comparer implementation for sorting on two properties (consider also nulls handling here):

```
public class CameraComparer : IComparer<Camera>
{
    private SortDirection typeSortDirection;
    private SortDirection nameSortDirection;

    public CameraComparer(SortDirection typeSortDirection, 
                          SortDirection nameSortDirection)
    {
        this.typeSortDirection = typeSortDirection;
        this.nameSortDirection = nameSortDirection;
    }

    public int Compare(Camera x, Camera y)
    {
        if (x.Type == y.Type)
            return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name) * 
           (nameSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? 1 : -1);

        return x.Type.CompareTo(y.Type) * 
           (typeSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? 1 : -1);
    }
}

public enum SortDirection
{
    Ascending,
    Descending
}
```

Usage:

```
myList.Sort(new CameraComparer(SortDirection.Ascending, SortDirection.Descending));
```

Comment: What is the best way to integrate my `asc` boolean into this to switch from Asc to Desc? Any shortcut or I shall use `if` statement?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see your update. Thanks, will check this now.

Comment: how can I change sorting order for `myList.OrderBy(x => x.type)`? `type` is integer.

Comment: @Pablo use `myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.type)` for Linq or use `CameraComparer` with `SortDirection.Descending`

Comment: I've just tried with Linq and got very odd result :) I've updated the code.

Comment: @Pablo looks fine, what odd did you get?

Comment: sorry, looks like the problem was in UI. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int Compare(Camera x, Camera y)
{
    if (x.type > y.type)
        return asc ? -1 : 1;

    if (x.type < y.type)
        return asc ? 1 : -1;

    if (x.name.CompareTo(y.name) > 0)
        return asc ? -1 : 1;

    if (x.name.CompareTo(y.name) < 0)
        return asc ? 1 : -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: name is a `string` type. Should I use `name.CompareTo()` ?

Comment: Could do, though not sure how `CompareTo` would work with your custom sort direction.

Comment: @Pablo Not really necessary, but it would be `return x.name.CompareTo(y.name)` instead of last two `if`s.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn: the code above will not even build, so I have to change it.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn: `Operator ">" cannot be applied to operands of type "string" and "string"`

Comment: @Pablo So use `CompareTo`.

Comment: That's what I did. I just commented because you said "it's not necessary". In fact it is.

Answer (score 1):

I use [`Tuple`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) for cases like this:

```
public int Compare(Camera x, Camera y) {
    var xx = Tuple.Create(x.name, x.type);
    var yy = Tuple.Create(y.name, y.type);
    return xx.CompareTo(yy);
}
```

That is, assuming that you want to compare all properties in the same order. If not, I *think* you could reverse the order in which a property (e.g. `name`) is considered by doing something like:

```
var xx = Tuple.Create(y.name, x.type);
var yy = Tuple.Create(x.name, y.type);
```

That is, putting it in the "wrong" tuple. But I haven't tested this part at all.